# Context-menu configuration not working in UICollection view when running in iPhone 7 iOS 15

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uicollectionview

I'm trying to add context menu option to UICollection view in iOS app. Here is my code. This code works recent iPhones like iPhone 12,13,14. But when I test it in iPhone 7 both physical device and simulator running iOS 15 it does not work. Context menu is not showing in iPhone 7. Do I need to implement Peek and Pop specifically for iPhone 7 as it supports 3D touch?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, contextMenuConfigurationForItemsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath], point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
    let configuration = UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil,previewProvider: nil){ _ in
        let delete = UIAction(title:"Delete",image: nil){ _ in
            print("Delete")
     
        }
        return UIMenu(title: "",options: .displayInline,children: [delete])
    }
    return configuration
 
}
```

Comment: Look at the documentation for the `collectionView(_:contextMenuConfigurationForItemsAt:point:)` delegate method. It's for iOS 16 or later.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it by using the contextMenuConfigurationForItemAt instead of the contextMenuConfigurationForItemsAt?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, contextMenuConfigurationForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
    let configuration = UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil,previewProvider: nil){ _ in
        let delete = UIAction(title:"Delete",image: nil){ _ in
            print("Delete")
     
        }
        return UIMenu(title: "",options: .displayInline,children: [delete])
    }
    return configuration
 
}
```

Comment: It would help if your answer pointed out that the method being used by the OP is only available for iOS 16+ which is why it isn't working under iOS 15. Point out that the method you suggest works with iOS 13+.